# How do you @use css custom properties?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, dom, sass

I am working on an app with custom theme settings allowing users to select a primary color which the app uses to generate a set of 10 tailwinds style color variables. I use javascript to generate the colors and inject them into the dom, but in my research I found out it wasn't possible to inject scss variables due to the dom only having access to the compiled css. Because of this, I had to use css custom properties instead of scss colors.

I am aware that this is an unusual use case and not how scss was intended to be used with colors, but rather than rewriting my project, I am hoping I can find an efficient solution to the problem.

```css
html {
    // Default Colors
    --color-primary-50: #F2F5FD;
    --color-primary-100: #E4EAFB;
    --color-primary-200: #C5D2F7;
    ...
}
```

```js
const setPalette = function setPaletteCSS(palette) {
    Object.entries(palette).forEach((entry) => {
        const [step, color] = entry;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
            `--color-primary-${step}`, 
            color
        );
    });
}
```

The code worked perfectly, but now my `main.scss` file has become too large and I am splitting it up using the 7-1 architecture pattern which has worked for other parts of the scss file until I tried to move these colors. To be specific, I moved the html component with the custom colors into `abstracts/_colors.scss`:

```
.
└── scss/
    ├── abstracts/
    │   ├── _colors.scss
    │   └── _index.scss
    └── main.scss
```

The main problem I have is that my components access these variables like so:

```
#site-header, #site-footer {
    color: var(--font-color);
    background-color: var(--color-primary-500);
}
```

I added `abstracts/colors` into my `main.scss` with `@use` like the other components, but I am not able to access these color properties any more.

```
@use './abstracts' as a;

#site-header, #site-footer {
    color: a.var(--font-color);
    background-color: a.var(--color-primary-500);
}
```

This results in webpack failing to compile my scss and showing the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
   ╷
49 │     color: a.var(--font-color);
   │            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

I understand the error but I do not know what my options are to resolve it. Since I am stuck using css custom properties for the colors, is there a way to `@use` them, or am I stuck with keeping all of my color related css within the same file?

Comment: You have your abstract folders with 2 files. Add an _index.scss file, and in it, forward the 2 files you have. That way when you use the abstract you have the 2 files being forwarded.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. There is already an `_index` file forwarding `_colors` in /abstracts. It has not given me access to the css properties though and I get that error.

Comment: I haven't found a way to use scss namespaces with css variables. It will work if you use `@use './abstracts' as *;`. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237519/using-sass-scss-to-generate-css-variables) has a good example on how to create themes using scss.

Comment: @dudule your response resolved my issue. I would be happy to pick your answer if you add it as an answer rather than a comment. Specifically, the `@use './abstracts' as *;` is what allowed me to refer to these properties in other files without the mass of errors I experienced before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to use SCSS namespaces with CSS variables.
It will work if you use `@use './abstracts' as *;`. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237519/using-sass-scss-to-generate-css-variables) has a good example on how to create themes using scss.